# JavaFX Dialog appears to block after closing, is not dismissed properly

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, alert

I am writing a little game; the game works as an application run from a server program to a client program. When client is connected to server, both users normally see open JFX windows of the game on their computer. However, in the Server class I would like to ask the user about game parameters using dialogs before starting the game. So far I have made dialogs that worked but only the window on the side of the client opened, on the server-side (the side that asks for user inputs via dialogs before game launch) the window did not open. Without sharing too much code here is the part that causes a problem (if I take the dialogs out of the picture the game works, but I would like to have the feature of inputting parameters):

```
private List<String> makeModalAndGetNames() {

    ...

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);

    ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Choisir les noms");
    ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Annuler", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();...
```

alert.close()}```
After simply calling this as-is in the start method, the server class won't load its own gui anymore :(. So I was wondering if anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong ? Should I handle events differently in the start method ? I am at quite a loss here.

Comment: Welcome @Quarantiner - If you are happy the issue is fixed, even by yourself, remember to close the question.

Comment: okay, I didn't have any other answer to accept than mine though so i accepted my own answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the details of why it worked but adding the lign `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` at the beginning of my program worked

Answer (score 0):

do this  code :

///////// alert ///////////////

Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);

```
    alert.setTitle("Message");

    alert.setHeaderText("Message :");

    alert.setContentText("write your message here");

    alert.showAndWait();
```